# How do I scale decode a FrameSupportDispatchPerDispatchClassWeight (in rust)?

Tags: weight, block-size

How do I scale decode a `FrameSupportDispatchPerDispatchClassWeight` ?
js seems the only definition I can find - can someone point to a rust definition please so I can decode it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the type that you are referring to is the storage type of `System.blockWeight()`.
It is defined as `PerDispatchClass<Weight>` (also called `ConsumedWeight`). The concrete `Weight` type is dependent in the runtime.

As example Polkadot:
To verify this you can head over to PolkadotJS and get the raw storage key for `System.blockWeight()` which is `0x26aa394eea5630e07c48ae0c9558cef734abf5cb34d6244378cddbf18e849d96`.
Then acquire a raw storage value for the last block, eg: `0xf0269f0d000000000000000000000000088d002374000000`.
This can then be decoded in Rust as such:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_decode_polkadot_works() {
    use frame_support::dispatch::PerDispatchClass;
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    type ConsumedWeight = PerDispatchClass<u64>;

    let data = hex::decode("f0269f0d000000000000000000000000100a0cd874000000").unwrap();
    let decoded  = ConsumedWeight::decode(&mut &data[..]).unwrap();
    let expected = ConsumedWeight::new(|c| match c {
        DispatchClass::Normal => 228534000,
        DispatchClass::Operational => 0,
        DispatchClass::Mandatory => 501840874000,
    });
    assert_eq!(decoded, expected);
}
```

Whereas in Kusama you need to use `PerDispatchClass<Weight>` which is WeightV2. One possible storage value is `0xb2ff8917000000070565d0158800`. Eg:

```rust
#[test]
fn test_decode_kusama_works() {
    use frame_support::dispatch::PerDispatchClass;
    use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
    type ConsumedWeight = PerDispatchClass<Weight>;

    let data = hex::decode("b2ff8917000000070565d0158800").unwrap();
    let decoded  = ConsumedWeight::decode(&mut &data[..]).unwrap();
    let expected = ConsumedWeight::new(|c| match c {
        DispatchClass::Normal => Weight::from_parts(98729964, 0),
        DispatchClass::Operational => Weight::from_parts(0, 0),
        DispatchClass::Mandatory => Weight::from_parts(584481531141, 0),
    });
    assert_eq!(decoded, expected);
}
```

Which used WeightV2, as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

While one might assume that it would be Compact for ref_time and proof_size based on [weights v2 source](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a92005a5092ebe6a636c96dcae814f9a378f5940/primitives/weights/src/weight_v2.rs#L29), it appears that the answer is they are (not compact) `u32`s when reading this state.